# Global, local and linearized observability

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, kalman-filter

I am working on a nonlinear system and i want to know how well its states can be estimated by a time-discrete estimator. Which kind of observability, i.e. global or local (for every possible state and input) would the system need to fullfill such that an estimator would converge to the true states for every possible trajectory?

I learned that local observability at a point can be sufficiently proved by the rank test using Lie derivatives. Is it possible to make a statement about the ability of the estimator to estimate the correct states if i use this rank test just at every timestep for the current states and inputs? 
Alternatively, do i gain any information about this ability by linearizing the system at every timestep and using the linear rank test? I already read that a nonlinear system can be observable at a point while its linearization is not.

For an Extended Kalman Filter which uses the linearization of the system in its algorithm, is it necessary that the linearized system is observable at every time?

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate the observability of the nonlinear system, you must use Lie derivatives. However, you might be interested to look at the following paper:

> Chen, Zhe, Ke Jiang, and James C. Hung. "Local observability matrix
> and its application to observability analyses." Conference of IEEE
> Industrial Electronics Society. 1990.

The linearized system is time-varying due to the computation of the Jacobians, so the local observability might be useful depending on your application. In some cases, the local observability of the linearized system is equivalent to the observability of the nonlinear system if the system is linearized using the true states. Unfortunately, the true state are not available in practice, so the local observability likely does not match the observability of the nonlinear system.

Nevertheless, the local observability is still a useful, but these things should be kept in mind.

Comment: @janick Did this answer your question? If so, please accept the answer, or if not, please let me know, and I would be happy to elaborate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the paper helped me, but there are some remaining questions:
If i got it correct, the author uses the linearization, which is time dependant to determine local observability at every timestep. But how do the results relate to the real nonlinear system?  Is it just a feature to check which conditions, like for example "Terrain slopes cannot be too small" could be helpful for the use of a kalman filter for this system? If i would use the local observability matrix will it prove wether the real nonlinear system is (not) observable (assuming true states)?

Comment: @janick The local observability tells us if the linearized system is observable. In other words, the nonlinear system is approximated by a linear system by performing linearization about a point. The local observability tells us if this linearized system is observable. However, this doesn't provide any concrete information about the observability of the nonlinear systems because the linearized system is not equivalent to the nonlinear system. In my experience, I have found local observability useful, if we are concerned with how an EKF might perform given the system is "almost" locally linear.

Comment: @janick Even if using true states, the local observability may not provide any information about the observability of the nonlinear system. This would require evaluating the nonlinear observability using Lie derivatives (and checking if this is the case). That may not be easy to do...

Comment: I think i could calculate the lie derivatives of the system but it can not be seen dircectly which rank the observability matrix has without knowing the actual inputs and states. Would it be enough  to evaluate the observability matrix at every time step to say something like "a perfect estimator would estimate the real state" (assuming perfectly known states for the use in the observability matrix) ?